# How to list root in screen login user list on Debian?

Tags: debian, login, root

Okay, so I can login to root acc on Debian (gnome), but I always have to click `Not listed?` and then pass `root` and password. Can I somehow make root appear in this screen login, so I would just click it and insert the password?

Comment: Not sure how to fix this, but logging in graphically as root seems not such a great idea. Better to become root in a terminal using `sudo` or `su`.

Comment: Why do you need that? I agree with eldering that using sudo is better.

Answer (score 0):

**I do not recommend logging into the root user, it can harm your system.**

You can enable it by executing this in the command line:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "greeter-show-manual-login=true" >> /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf'
```

It may ask for the password, you can change that this way:

```
sudo passwd root
```